# Convert PKCS#12 Certificate to JKS format and save the certificate in JKS format with the help of JAVA

Tags: java, ssl, x509certificate, jks, pkcs#12

I have been stuck in a situation where i have a Keystore.jks in my configuration folder.
Now from GUI i have to add a certificate+key in P12 format and store this certificate in Keystore.jks. When a user add the certificate then passphrase is also required to be added.
All this i have to do with the help of Java. I cannot use direct commands present in Keytool or openssl. I have to do it programmatically.

Comment: Possible dublicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18889058/programmatically-import-ca-trust-cert-into-existing-keystore-file-without-using

Comment: You should read iterate over content of p12 keystore and populate jks keystore with content. Class [java.security.KeyStore](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/security/KeyStore.html) has nesessary methods. Check [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3027273/how-to-store-and-load-keys-using-java-security-keystore-class), for example

Comment: the issue is resolved. Actually the requirement was that i need the pass-phrase to just load the pkcs12 container. Thanks everyone for you reply.